# Remove null from list string c#

Tags: c#

Seems it was answered a few times already but it's not working for me...

I have a list  called combox. I want to remove null items.

I wrote:

```
   List<String> comboxTable = new List<string>();  
    comboxTable = comboxTable.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
```

but I'm getting:

> Error 14  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I tried this one:

```
comboxTable = comboxTable.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
```

Same error.
Where is the 'int'?
What am I doing wrong?

(Combox is getting its string value someplace else in the code and has Nulls here and there. I want to delete them)

Comment: `comboxTable.RemoveAll(item => item == null);` is enough, dont assign.... `int` is return type of `RemoveAll` which is the number of elements removed.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx). `RemoveAll()` returns an integer and your code tries to cast it to an object of type `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Change your code to this:

```
comboxTable.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
```

and it will work. The `null` items will be removed. `RemoveAll` operates on the instance itself it does not return a new one

Comment: ...and also the empty strings and "     "s. Which was not the task. The point is that RemoveAll() modifies the instance itself and returns the number of elements removed

Comment: @g.pickardou Added further explanation

Answer (score 5):

RemoveAll() modifies the instance itself and returns the number of elements removed

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq:

```
List<String> comboxTable = new List<string>();  
comboxTable = comboxTable.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m)).ToList();
```

Comment: No linq necessary here, and also creating a new list instance is an overhead

Comment: @g.pickardou ... accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like below code
            comboxTable.RemoveAll(var => String.IsNullOrEmpty(var));